# How to use local calendar in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

MediaWiki release notes says that it supports Iranian calendar since version 1.12
But I'm not able to change the calendar.  Can anybody help me do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just editing your `LocalSettings.php` with:

```
$wgLocaltimezone = "Asia/Tehran";
```

should be enough, unless you mean something else by "calendar". See [Manual:Timezone](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Timezone) for more.